# Error - USPS Address Verfication PHP API

Tags: php, xml, usps

I have download the code & create demo from "https://github.com/VinceG/USPS-php-api" for USPS-php-api.

I got error like this "Array ( ) bool(true) Error: No URL set! "

Please let me know if you have any solution.

I have used following code.

---

```
<?php
require_once('../USPSAddressVerify.php');
$verify = new USPSAddressVerify('xxxxxxxxxxxx'); // I have used correct username
$address = new USPSAddress;
$address->setFirmName('Apartment');
$address->setApt('100');
$address->setAddress('9200 Milliken Ave');
$address->setCity('Rancho Cucomonga');
$address->setState('CA');
$address->setZip5(91730);
$address->setZip4('');

$verify->addAddress($address);
print_r($verify->verify());
print_r($verify->getArrayResponse());
var_dump($verify->isError());

if($verify->isSuccess()) {
    echo 'Done';
} else {
    echo 'Error: ' . $verify->getErrorMessage();
}
```

---

Comment: What is the url set in USPSAddressVerify.php?

Comment: Note the author's open issue on GitHub, where the solution should be posted as well: https://github.com/VinceG/USPS-php-api/issues/5

Comment: I was able to recreate the error by commenting out line#136 - `$opts[CURLOPT_URL] = self::$testMode ? self::TEST_API_URL : self::LIVE_API_URL ;` in `USPSBase.php`. Make sure that you are setting `$opts[CURLOPT_URL]`.

Comment: @Sean : I have comment this line but it gives error like this "80040b1a Authorization failure. You are not authorized to connect to this server. UspsCom::DoAuth"

Comment: Your question sounds like a support request in using that library. I don't want to say you should not ask in the internet about the problems you run into, however here on Stackoverflow this is about practical, answerable and concrete programming questions. And providing support for a library you install for the first time and you get an error message with (and now the second), does not work well for the format of this website. Instead contact the vendor of the library for your support options.

Answer (score 0):

What I did is in the `USPSBase` class, in the `doRequest` method, comment out this line...

```
$opts[CURLOPT_URL] = self::$testMode ? self::TEST_API_URL : self::LIVE_API_URL
```

...and modify this line...

```
$ch = curl_init();
```

..to be...

```
$ch = curl_init(self::$testMode ? self::TEST_API_URL : self::LIVE_API_URL);
```

...and, with a potentially related issue, I had to add...

```
$opts[CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION] = !ini_get('open_basedir');
```

...after...

```
$opts[CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS] = http_build_query($this->getPostData(), null, '&');
```

...to satisfy this warning...

```
curl_setopt_array(): CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION cannot be activated when an open_basedir is set
```

**NOTE: this has only been tested with the address verification functionality!**